# Find a string within a char [ ] [ ]

Tags: java, string, char

I'm trying to find a String within a `char[][]`, so I thought I could convert the **char into a String** and use `s1.contains(string)` where `s1` is a **String object**,but that does not seem to work out as the char is 2-dimensional array.
Is there another way or am I on the right track?

Comment: Define and describe your conversion strategy.

Comment: When you interpret your char array as an array of Strings, this should work.

Comment: What @Smutje said... your array of char arrays is like an array of Strings.

Comment: Thx for the quick answers, I will try to make it work

Comment: Be careful if you do concatenate your array of strings into one string-- it would be easy to misinterpret whether "bc" should be found within the array {"ab","cd"}.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
for(char [] a : arr){
    s.add(new String(a));
}
```

Where `arr` is the two dimensional array and `s` is an `ArrayList<String>` (just an example you are of course free to do what you will with your strings :) ).

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/k545OA).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as:

```
char char2d[][];
String charString = "";

for(int i = 0 ; i < char2d.length; i++){
  charString = charString + new String(char2d[i]);
}
```

Now check for required string

```
charString.contains(string);
```

It could help you.

Comment: You are also looping over char array and creating a string from char[] in line s.add(new String(a)); and i also looping over and passing char[] in string constructor. Then where is the problem ??